# Obtaining r-squared values from cumSeg/step-function fit

Tags: r, regression

I know its possible to extract r-squared values to quantify the 'goodness-of-fit' of regressions in R, with something to the effect of:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata)  # Not actual data
r-sq <- summary(fit)$r.squared # or $adj.r.squared
```

I've recently been using the `cumSeg` package for step-function regressions, but it doesn't appear to offer this functionality, though it does provide residuals as a vector.

Is there some way to extract an r-squared (or adj. r squared) that I don't know about? Or can it be calculated 'de novo' with something that `cumSeg` does actually provide?

**EDIT**
This is the output of `summary()` for my stepfunction created via `cumSeg`. Perhaps someone more mathematically versed with stepfunctions knows if the  nomenclature for an r-squared (or whatever the equivalent is) is just different and the data I'm looking for is actually there (or if it is even a legitimate question to ask for an R-squared for stepfunctions?! I'm assuming it should be calculable from any fitted model really.

```
> summary(stepfunc)
              Length Class  Mode   
coefficients   3     -none- numeric
residuals     16     -none- numeric
effects       16     -none- numeric
rank           1     -none- numeric
fitted.values 16     -none- numeric
assign         0     -none- NULL   
qr             5     qr     list   
df.residual    1     -none- numeric
epsilon        1     -none- numeric
it             1     -none- numeric
psi            1     -none- numeric
beta.c         1     -none- numeric
gamma.c        1     -none- numeric 
V             16     -none- numeric
y             16     -none- numeric
id.group      16     -none- numeric
est.means      2     -none- numeric
n.psi          1     -none- numeric
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract what you need directly from your result with squared brackets []. Here an example:

```
set.seed(your seed)    

dt <- data.frame(fc = rep(sample(0:100, 100, replace = TRUE), 
100), v1 =     rep(rnorm(100, 0, 1), 100), v2 = rep(rnorm(100, 0, 2), 100))

fit <- lm(fc ~ v1 + v2, data = dt)  # Not actual data

summary(fit)[9]

$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.01484017
```

Otherwise, you can look for the `$` operator in this way:

```
summary(fit$effects)
```

It will show you a list of possible parameters you could be interested in.

Comment: Yes that's what I would ordinarily have done with packages like `lm`, but the fit that `cumSeg` creates doesn't seem to offer that. I've edited by answer to show what the output of `summary()` of my stepfunction gives.

Comment: Brackets is the way R itself indexes, with double brackets in the case of lists, for example. Try to execute `class` on your output, and to find the correct indexing procedure. I could try, but, in order to to that, I need at least a sample of the code that produced your summary. Posted here, the output does not provide many useful information.

Comment: The exact data/code I'm using is given in a related question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728663/make-step-function-adopt-90-degree-transitions/36775063#36775063. `stepfunc` is my fit to the `GC` data in that code.